# Access parent state's scope (nested views)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Given a multi-step form, each step has its own route.

There's a progress bar indicating what the current step is.

I set up the routes like this:

- stateRoot (abstract) containing the progress bar

  - stateRoot.index (child of stateRoot)
  - stateRoot.step1 (child of stateRoot)
  - ...

What is the best way to update the progress bar's state?

Comment: You could `$emit` an event from the child controller(s) whenever the step changes, or use a service to keep track of the steps and `$watch` the appropriate service variable for changes. In this situation, unless you have other data that needs to be shared between the states, I'd use the `$emit` solution.

Comment: @Fissio Thanks for the answer.